# What are some efficent solutions to check if arrayA contains all elements of arrayB?

Tags: java, c++

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {

        for (int y = 0; y < arrayB.length; y++) {
            if (arrayA[i] == arrayB[y]) {
                cnt++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (cnt == arrayB.length) {
        // B is subset of A
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert arrays into `lists` and use `containsAll` method to check this, e.g.:

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(a);
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(b);
list1.containsAll(list2);
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection))'s javadoc for `containsAll` method.

**Update**

Here's how it will work in case of `int` arrays:

```
int[] a = new int[10];
int[] b = new int[10];
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.stream(b).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
list1.containsAll(list2);
```

Comment: What if it is array if primitive type like `int[]`? It is worth mentioning that `Arrays.asList` will not handle this case correctly and we will need other way to fill our Lists.

Comment: Based on array type, we can change the collection type accordingly. If it's primitive, we can even use `stream` and box it.

Comment: That is very true. IMO It is worth putting it in answer.

Comment: Updated the answer, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Another aspect worth mentioning is that for situation like `{1}.containsAll{1,1}` (where `{x}` represents list with `x` elements) will get as response `true`. `containsAll` simply checks if each element from tested collection exist in original collection (here each `1` exist in original collection `{1}`). So it doesn't care about number of elements, but about their equality.